# A terminal emulator for ex-Windows users

Tags: gnome-terminal

There are several things I would like to be better in Ubuntu Terminal Emulator.

- coloring, like in the source code
- Copy and paste keyboard shortcuts that I used all the time in Windows: `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-V`

(Most of people here in Ubuntu use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V keyboard shortcuts to copy and paste everywhere *except* the terminal! I think it's annoying for newcomers, and I don't worry about historical reasons)

- A feature to save all the output to log file

---

**UPDATE:**

Can the terminal be a powerful feature-full user-friendly tool like a modern IDE? The Linux user can spend 30% of time in the terminal. Programmers no longer code in a notepad. Can I see the history pane? Suggestions? Directory pane? Commands list? Search for words in an output? Contextual behavior? "Search in Google" for a mouse right-click. Tips and tricks learning?

Time is money! Please, people, give me a link to the 21st - century terminal.

Comment: Output data to log file. `ls > file.txt`. Search for words in output `ls | grep .jpg`.

Comment: I find your title amusing because Gnome-terminal is much more featured than the default Windows terminal.

Comment: @root45 Yep, you are right, but Windows has a lot of administrating utils where everything is sorted nicely. I've not used terminal in Windows much

Comment: The terminal copy/paste commands are Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V, at least in `gnome-terminal` and `konsole`.

Answer (score 2):

### Try CLI Companion:

What you are looking for is CLI Companion. It has just about all the features you are looking for, and then some :). Code colouring comes with your terminal's profile and some other terminal settings, so you should configure that in your GNOME Terminal preferences, and possibly install BashstyleNG as well.

### To install CLI Companion:

Add the ppa:

```
ppa:clicompanion-devs/clicompanion-nightlies
```

And then update your sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install clicompanion:

```
sudo apt-get install clicompanion
```

*I will add screenshots and a bit more info later, as I am not on my main laptop where I have it installed.*

Answer (score 1):

The second task can be done running following commands in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/copy "<Control>c"
gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/paste "<Control>v"
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: But this breaks the ability to kill running process using `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 1):

Hotwire (available in Software Center) is a project to implement a terminal and shell using modern UI conventions. It's like a cross between a terminal/shell and a GUI file manager, with pop-up command suggestion and other handy features. It handles ctrl-C and ctrl-V as copy and paste.

I don't think such projects they tend to be very widely used because anytime they change something, tools adapted to traditional terminals get less convenient to use. For example, without traditional ctrl-C, the main way of stopping a runaway program disappears, so the author would have to add in some other way to accomplish that. It's a big project to re-work an entire operating environment without losing any functionality, and hard to convince a potential audience that your way of doing it is the one to switch to and learn.

Answer (score 0):

actually, the Gnome-terminal do the coloring part. For the example, use the change directory command, `cd` and navigate into a folder, sometimes you see things colorful. The color differentiate things into folders, files with different permissions, archives and so on.

and for the second task, the cut and paste key required additional keyboard button to be pressed, that is the `shift` button. If you are already know about the shift button, ignore this :D  (actually, it is pretty hard for me too to press the shift button, already accustomed with `ctrl + c`  button since little kid... haha